# create PopUpMenu in side onCreateOptionsMenu()

Tags: android, menu, popupmenu

Hii i want to create a `PopUpMenu` inside the `onCreateOptionMenu()` i am targeting API level 10 and my `minSdk` version is 8 for tablet as you know there is no hard menu key so for soft menu key   i am using `onCreateOtionMenu()` to create a menu option below my screen and it is also working.when i am presssing the Soft menuOption in my screen its displaying the `PopUpMenu`  for the firsttime and the next time onwards its not showing anything.

here is my code snippets for `PopUpMenu` inside `OnCreateOptionssMenu()` method

```
  @Override 
    public boolean  onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    PopUpMenu popup=new PopUpMenu(this,txtView);
                        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.option,popup.getMenu());
     popup.show();

                        //popup.dismiss();
                        //menu.clear();
                        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.fragmenttwo_menu, menu);
                            return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));


                        }
```

**Note:** here txtView is a TextView you can say a view Anchor below that i am displaying the PopUpMenu Items.
**For calrification here i am using `ViewPager`**

Comment: Move it to your onCreate method. This should fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay but my question when i will  presss the soft menu key it should display the  PopUpMenu items.if i will take it onCreate() method its throwing NullPointerException.i cant call   popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.option,popup.getMenu()); in Oncreate() method.

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621070/get-context-of-popupmenu-like-contextmenu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After did lots of R&D i found that with `softmenu` key Displaying `PopUpMenu` for `target version 10` is not possible.`PopUpMenu` is only available after 11+ API Level.In my case sometimes its displaying and some time its not displaying.If you have any solution please let me inform.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this way :

```
 @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU && event.getAction() == 0) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "hii", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

**Edited:**
in above code there is `Toast` that's why it `dismiss` after some time. its depend on your code what you done inside method. now check below code. `dialog` is show till you `dismiss` it.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU && event.getAction() == 0) {

            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, lView);
            popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main,
                    popupMenu.getMenu());
            popupMenu.show();

            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

**Hope You Understand....**

Comment: same as it was before popup is showing for sometime then disappears.

Comment: Hey are getting my question  i want to display a PopUpMenu inside onKeyDown() its displaying but suddenly disappears.i will edit your answar hope you will catch my point.

Comment: What is `lView`?

Answer (score 0):

I used the user1381827's answer but then realized that the menu keeps disappearing. Here is the code that I ended up with:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU && event.getAction() == 1) {
        ImageView v = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.header);
        showHeaderMenu(v);
        return false;
    }

    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    return true;
}
```

But in general case last 2 lines may/should be replaced with just

```
return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
```